# Phoenix Hbase rowtimestamp feature not working when bulk loading

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am using **hbase1.1** and **phoenix 4.9.0.**

I am mapping  my phoenix table's **date** field to hbase timestamp using phoenix **rowtimestamp** feature.
it's working fine with upsert query.
when i am **bulk loading** data into it, it's not taking effect.it takes only bulk loading time as hbase timestamp.

eg: ttl feature : it's considering bulk loaded time only..

is this a bug or for bulk loadiing the feature is not there?
can anyone explain.

thanks in advance

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: hi Jan,
it was a bug in the phoenix 4.9.0. it's fixed in phoenix 4.12.0 release.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug and the fix is integrated in apache-phoenix 4.12.0 release.